# Calculating rolling investment in R (by reinvesting returns)

Tags: r, loops, return, finance

I have a dataframe:

```
> df
    date group return
1 197501     A  1.020
2 197502     A  1.050
3 197503     A  1.031
4 197504     A  0.970
5 197501     B  0.990
6 197502     B  1.023
7 197503     B  1.040
8 197504     B  1.050
```

I want to create a new column 'inv' indicating the growth of my investment, i.e. I invest 1,000,000 in 197501 and I then need to calculate the return of my investment (plus it's return from last month). Furthermore, I have groups meaning that each time a new group starts the first row should start by 1,000,000 * return.

This means that:

In row 1, I want

```
1,000,000 * 1.020 = 1,020,000
```

In row 2 I then want

```
1,020,000 * 1.050 = 1,071,000
```

etc.

In row 5 (group b) I want

```
1,000,000 * 0.990 = 990,000
```

In row 6 (group b) I want

```
990,000 * 1.023 = 1,012,770
```

etc.

The end result should look like this:

```
    date group return        inv
1 197501     A  1.020 1020000.00
2 197502     A  1.050 1071000.00
3 197503     A  1.031 1104201.00
4 197504     A  0.970 1071075.97
5 197501     B  0.990  990000.00
6 197502     B  1.023 1012770.00
7 197503     B  1.040 1053281.80
8 197504     B  1.050 1105945.84
```

How can I do this in R?

Answer (score 0):

We can use `cumprod` after doing a group by operation

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df %>% 
         group_by(group) %>%
         mutate(inv = 1000000 *cumprod(return)) %>%
         ungroup
```

-output

```
df1
# A tibble: 8 x 4
#    date group return      inv
#   <int> <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 197501 A       1.02 1020000 
#2 197502 A       1.05 1071000.
#3 197503 A       1.03 1104201 
#4 197504 A       0.97 1071075.
#5 197501 B       0.99  990000 
#6 197502 B       1.02 1012770 
#7 197503 B       1.04 1053281.
#8 197504 B       1.05 1105945.
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$inv <- with(df, 1000000 * ave(return, group, FUN = cumprod))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(date = c(197501L, 197502L, 197503L, 197504L, 197501L, 
197502L, 197503L, 197504L), group = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", 
"B", "B", "B"), return = c(1.02, 1.05, 1.031, 0.97, 0.99, 1.023, 
1.04, 1.05)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8"))
```